# My html form / php form keeps returning my error else message, it is not pulling from the database

Tags: php, html, forms

The problem may be here in the html form, but this is linked correctly

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="mod2_findrecord.php"> 
        <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1"  cellpadding="2">
                 <tr>
                    <td width="100">Last Name</td>
                    <td><input name="last_name" type="text" id = "last_name"></td>
                 </tr> 

                 <tr>
                    <td width="100"> </td>
                    <td>
                       <input name="find" type="submit" id="add" value="Find Record">
                    </td>
                 </tr>

              </table>
           </form>
</body>
</html>


    <?php
include 'mod2_opendb.php';
include 'mod2_config.php';

$lastname = (isset($_POST['last_name'])    ? $_POST['last_name']   : '');

$sql= " SELECT employeeid, managementid, first_name, last_name, age, employment_period FROM employees WHERE last_name = '$lastname' ";
```

This SQL statement works in my database

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<b>Record found</b><br>";
        echo "<b>EmployeeID: " . $row["employeeid"]. "</b><br>";
        echo "<b>ManagementID: " . $row["managementid"]. "</b><br>";
echo "<b>Name: " . $row["first_name"]. " " . $row["last_name"]. "</b><br>";
        echo "<b>Age: " . $row["age"]. "</b><br>";
        echo "<b>Employment Period In Months: " .    $row["employment_period"]. "</b><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Sorry there are no matches! Please check your entry and try again.";
}
```

This is the message that keeps displaying, it does not allow me to pull information

```
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: I don't see opening `<form>`

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and will be hacked** even if [you are escaping inputs!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741264/2595450) Use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Don't mix your question text and HTML code, the HTML isn't showing up properly.

Comment: What is the error your getting?

Comment: It keeps echoing this message:  else {
    echo "Sorry there are no matches! Please check your entry and try again.";

Comment: @CodingTime if what you are seeing in the browser includes the `else { echo` part, that means your server isn’t parsing the PHP at all. Are you really seeing that in the browser?

Comment: I'm not seeing the else part. I am only seeing the message that is telling me that there is no matches in the database, but the name I am entering is in the database. I am asking why it is telling me that it is not in the database.